# How to check a value in a textbox and if it hasn't changed for 3 seconds do something, otherwise check again in 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my attempt but I believe 'checker(thisVal)' is the part which is causing problems.

```
  $("#search-input").keyup(function () {
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        if(thisVal!=''){

            var checker = function (v){
                if($(this).val() !=v){
                    setTimeout('checker(thisVal)', 3000);
                }
                else{
                    console.log($(this).val());
                }
            }
            setTimeout(function(){checker(thisVal)}, 3000);

        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: He can't pass the value into setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

I believe  you want this for the timeOut line:

```
 setTimeout(function(){checker(thisVal)}, 3000);
```

Edit: Try this code.

```
$("#search-input").keyup(function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    if (thisVal !== '') {

        var checker = function(v) {
            if (thisVal !== v) {
                setTimeout('checker(thisVal)', 3000);
            }
            else {
                console.log(thisVal);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            checker(thisVal)
        }, 3000);
    }
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar5vc/1/).

Comment: That solved the error but now I have a new one here: console.log($(this).val()); Please see my edited code. Thank you.

Comment: The error is Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined and points to the console.log line

Comment: That's because `this` has changed when checker is called from setTimeout rather than from the keyup event.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){checker.call($('#search-input').get(0), thisVal)}, 3000);
```

Using `Function.call` allows you define `this` when the function runs.  When `checker` runs from the `keyup` event, `this` is the input element.  When it runs from `setInterval`, `this` is normally the window object.  The `call` function lets you set `this` to the input element again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would take a different approach to the problem

```
var that = $(this);
var thisVal = that.val();
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
  if(that.val() === thisVal){
    console.log(thisVal);        
  }        
}, 3000);

clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);//will stop the checks
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this...

Take a look at this library:
http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Also, I made you an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/g8ShH/

Hope this helps :-)